# Modifcar los valores de un array de objetos en php

Tags: php, array, objeto

Tengo el siguiente response

```
[
{
    "resultados": [
        {
            "seller_id": "102",
            "shop_url": "",
            "shop_title": "",
            "logo_pic": "Tienda.png",
            "company_locality": "San Juena",
            "store_id": "1",
            "allowed_categories": ""
        },
        {
            "seller_id": "102",
            "shop_url: "",
            "shop_title": null,
            "logo_pic": luz.jpg,
            "company_locality": null,
            "store_id": "0",
            "allowed_categories": ""
        },
        {
            "seller_id": "99",
            "shop_url": "Asss",
            "shop_title": "saew",
            "logo_pic": "1817893888095_n.jpg",
            "company_locality": "Lomas altas",
            "store_id": "1",
            "allowed_categories": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

]

Necesito modificar cada objeto en el campo "logo_pic" agregando el siguiente valor "https://es.stackoverflow.com/" + el valor que tiene en este caso quedaria asi el primer valor https://es.stackoverflow.com/Tienda.jpg

He estado intentando ingresar a los valores de los objetos, pero solo logro imprimir los valores y no los keys, de la siguiente manera

```
$valoresArray = $response["resultados"];

return $valoresArray[0];
```

asi solo me devuelve los valores de esa posicion, y no los keys, no se que sera :(

Comment: Pero que has intentado? en el código que pones no veo nada relacionado con tu pregunta... además el foreach tiene un return... porque te sales en la primera iteracion?

Comment: no me habia dado cuenta que el array es solo de una posicion, adentro de esa posicion vienen los objetos

Comment: no veo intención de solicitar ayuda, sino que te hagan el código.....

Comment: @John veo que tienes poca reputacion, ahora se por que, saludos.

Comment: @Geracros Gracias

Comment: `foreach($array as $key=> $value)` eso podría ayudarte, [el manual, el manual](https://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: @Geracros, basandome en tu ejemplo de response, la forma correcta de acceder a los resultados debería ser `$response[0]["resultados"]`. Si actualmente obtenes los resultados con tú código algo en tu pregunta no es correcto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeramente, se agradecen datos válidos cuando plantees una pregunta. Tus datos no lo son. El elemento que muestras en la pregunta [no valida](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#).

Los nombres de propiedad deben ir entre comillas (aquí falta una):

```
"shop_url: "",
```

Igualmente, los valores de tipo String deben ir entre comillas (aquí faltan las dos):

```
"logo_pic": luz.jpg,
```

En segundo lugar, si tú quieres modificar un elemento en PHP, al leerlo, debes [**pasarlo por referencia**](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.references.pass.php) usando `&`.

En esta estructura, puedes crear un objeto, si no lo tienes ya creado, y en la lectura del bucle, pasarlo por referencia.

Veamos un ejemplo completo, partiremos del dato como cadena (si lo tienes como de otro modo puedes obviar a `$data`, pero **asegurándote de que sea un JSON válido en su origen**, es una condición obligatoria para que tu código funcione.

Veamos:

```
$data='[
  {
    "resultados":[
      {
        "seller_id":"102",
        "shop_url":"",
        "shop_title":"",
        "logo_pic":"Tienda.png",
        "company_locality":"San Juena",
        "store_id":"1",
        "allowed_categories":""
      },
      {
        "seller_id":"102",
        "shop_url":"",
        "shop_title":null,
        "logo_pic":"luz.jpg",
        "company_locality":null,
        "store_id":"0",
        "allowed_categories":""
      },
      {
        "seller_id":"99",
        "shop_url":"Asss",
        "shop_title":"saew",
        "logo_pic":"1817893888095_n.jpg",
        "company_locality":"Lomas altas",
        "store_id":"1",
        "allowed_categories":""
      }
    ]
  }
]';

#URL que se usará para la sustitución
$url="https://es.stackoverflow.com/";

#Convertimos los datos a un objeto, para poder iterar
$json=json_decode($data);
#Test del objeto original
var_dump($json);
#Nótese la &, indica que cada $item
#será pasado por referencia
#y por tanto podrá modificarse
foreach ($json[0]->resultados as &$item){
    $item->logo_pic=sprintf("%s%s",$url,$item->logo_pic);
}
#Test del objeto modificado
var_dump($json);
```

**Salida:**

El objeto sin modificar:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#4 (1) {
    ["resultados"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      object(stdClass)#1 (7) {
        ["seller_id"]=>
        string(3) "102"
        ["shop_url"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["shop_title"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["logo_pic"]=>
        string(10) "Tienda.png"
        ["company_locality"]=>
        string(9) "San Juena"
        ["store_id"]=>
        string(1) "1"
        ["allowed_categories"]=>
        string(0) ""
      }
      [1]=>
      object(stdClass)#2 (7) {
        ["seller_id"]=>
        string(3) "102"
        ["shop_url"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["shop_title"]=>
        NULL
        ["logo_pic"]=>
        string(7) "luz.jpg"
        ["company_locality"]=>
        NULL
        ["store_id"]=>
        string(1) "0"
        ["allowed_categories"]=>
        string(0) ""
      }
      [2]=>
      object(stdClass)#3 (7) {
        ["seller_id"]=>
        string(2) "99"
        ["shop_url"]=>
        string(4) "Asss"
        ["shop_title"]=>
        string(4) "saew"
        ["logo_pic"]=>
        string(19) "1817893888095_n.jpg"
        ["company_locality"]=>
        string(11) "Lomas altas"
        ["store_id"]=>
        string(1) "1"
        ["allowed_categories"]=>
        string(0) ""
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

El objeto modificado:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#4 (1) {
    ["resultados"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      object(stdClass)#1 (7) {
        ["seller_id"]=>
        string(3) "102"
        ["shop_url"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["shop_title"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["logo_pic"]=>
        string(39) "https://es.stackoverflow.com/Tienda.png"
        ["company_locality"]=>
        string(9) "San Juena"
        ["store_id"]=>
        string(1) "1"
        ["allowed_categories"]=>
        string(0) ""
      }
      [1]=>
      object(stdClass)#2 (7) {
        ["seller_id"]=>
        string(3) "102"
        ["shop_url"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["shop_title"]=>
        NULL
        ["logo_pic"]=>
        string(36) "https://es.stackoverflow.com/luz.jpg"
        ["company_locality"]=>
        NULL
        ["store_id"]=>
        string(1) "0"
        ["allowed_categories"]=>
        string(0) ""
      }
      [2]=>
      &object(stdClass)#3 (7) {
        ["seller_id"]=>
        string(2) "99"
        ["shop_url"]=>
        string(4) "Asss"
        ["shop_title"]=>
        string(4) "saew"
        ["logo_pic"]=>
        string(48) "https://es.stackoverflow.com/1817893888095_n.jpg"
        ["company_locality"]=>
        string(11) "Lomas altas"
        ["store_id"]=>
        string(1) "1"
        ["allowed_categories"]=>
        string(0) ""
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### Demo

<kbd>[**`Ver en Rextester`**](https://rextester.com/MDOWA38917)</kbd>

Comment: Muchas gracias por todo, lo probe y me funciono!! Soy principiante en PHP, asi que todo el conocimiento que me compartiste, lo investigare para seguir aprendiendo.

Comment: Me alegro de que te haya servido @Geracros. Saludos.